# Debugging a lazarus program that loads a visual studio dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lazarus, freepascal

I have written a library (DLL) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and a GUI in Lazarus 1.6.4. The Lazarus application loads the DLL correctly and is able to call all the functions correctly.

When I start the application from Lazarus, and set my breakpoints before starting the application, debugging works as expected.
However, when the application is running, and I try to add a breakpoint, I receive an external SIGSEGV exception. This exception occurs in ntdll function ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory. Running the debugger from Visual Studio causes no crash. I need both as they use different debugging formats. (Could that also be the cause of the problem?)

The program is compiled as 32-bit executable running on 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: This could just be a first chance exception that your debugging is failing to ignore

Comment: If I continue, I get one more exception, then a Windows "program has crashed" dialog.

Comment: Something seems wrong. But with no [mcve] it's hard for us to help.

Comment: You can try in the lazarus tools > options, debugger, in the grid to enable `DisableLoadSymbolsForLibraries`